# Rownumber >100 and rownumber < 200

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I am new at this forum and I have a question pls:
I have a mssql database and the code below runs perfect on mssql server management studio 2012.

```
SELECT  siparis_detay.[kodu] as [Urun_kodu]
,siparisler.[id] as [Siparis_No]
,[firmaadi]   
,siparisler.[kodu] as Siparis_Kodu    
,siparisler.[tarih] as tarih1
,siparisler.[eposta]
,uyelik.[haberdar]
,uyelik.[onay]
,siparisler.[uy_id]
FROM siparis_detay 
INNER JOIN siparisler ON siparis_detay.sp_id = siparisler.id 
INNER JOIN urunler ON siparis_detay.kodu = urunler.kodu 
INNER JOIN uyelik ON siparisler.uy_id = uyelik.id
where siparisler.[durum] like 'kargo%' and siparis_detay.kodu='ac011' 
and uyelik.[haberdar]=0 and uyelik.[onay]=1
group by siparis_detay.[kodu],firmaadi,siparisler.[id],siparisler.
[kodu],siparisler.[tarih],siparisler.[eposta], siparisler.[uy_id],
uyelik.[haberdar],uyelik.[onay]
order by siparisler.id desc
```

The result set of the above query is +500 records and I want to display them like this: first from 0 to 100, then 100 to 200.. until I reach the end of the data.

the below code is a simple example of how I did I a similar thing (but it was a 1 table query maybe that's why it worked ok) and it works just the way I want so I wanted to apply the same code to the 3 tabled query above but I get the "multipart identifier could not be bound" error all the time..
that query which works is below:

```
SELECT id, adsoyad,  eposta,onay,haberdar,kayit
from
(
SELECT  id, adsoyad,  eposta,onay,haberdar,kayit,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS Rownumber
FROM  [mentesoglu_B2B].[dbo].[uyelik]
)as t
WHERE haberdar =0 and onay=1 and Rownumber >100 and rownumber < 200
```

so my question is:how can I make this incremental filtering (fe records from 100 to 200) work with my 3 joined table query without getting errors.

thx in advance

Comment: *"multipart identifier could not be bound"* isn't the full error. Post the **full** error. I also suggest learning to use white space in your SQL; that's very difficult to read. Here's a place to start that might help: [SQL Style Guide](https://www.sqlstyle.guide/)

Comment: Looks like you want to implement paging, take a look at the [`FETCH/OFFSET` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned)

Comment: `GROUP BY` across all columns in the `SELECT` list is a) easier done just by specifying `DISTINCT` in that clause and b) using either option an admittance that your query isn't properly constrained, you're getting duplicate results, and *rather than trying to work out why* you're just giving up and admitting defeat.

Comment: @DavidG [NO OFFSET](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Comment: Ive checked my database to see that it was created with mssql version 2008 so I can't use fetch-offset command which was introduced in 2012.